# Evento keydown se pierde al abrir modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un slide creado con la libreria blueimp.js En el slide necesito leer cuando el usuario pulsa la tecla B o C. Hasta aqui todo bien, el detalle es que cuando se abre y cierra un modal, se pierde la lectura del evento keydown y solo se activa de nuevo cuando reinicio el Slide.

Dejo mi código que utilizo:

```
// Ejecutar Slide
initSlide: function(){
    let that = this;
    $('#links').click(function(event){
        let options = {
                index: link,
                onopen: function(){
                    that.opts.readKeydown = true;
                },
                onslideend: function(index, slide){
                    that.keyDownReader(index);
                },
                onclose: function(){
                    that.opts.readKeydown = false;
                },
            };

        blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
    });
},

// Ejecutar cuando usuario pulse las teclas B:66 y C:67
keyDownReader: function(index){
    let that = this;
    console.log(index, that.opts.readKeydown);
    $('#links').keydown(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (that.opts.readKeydown) {
            switch (event.which || event.keyCode) {
                case 66: // b --> Checkbox Book
                    $('modalB').modal('show');
                  break
                case 67: // c --> Checkbox Cover
                    $('modalC').modal('show');
                  break
            }
        }
    });
},
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar, a saber por que se pierde el evento. De antemano gracias!
NOTA: Si ocupan más detalles, solo pregunten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**R E S U E L T O**

Solo tenia que leer el evento desde $(document.body) y no en $('#links'), porque cuando abro y cierro el modal el foco se regresa al body.

```
$(document.body).keydown(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (that.opts.readKeydown) {
      switch (event.which || event.keyCode) {
          case 66: // b --> Checkbox Book
              $('modalB').modal('show');
            break
          case 67: // c --> Checkbox Cover
              $('modalC').modal('show');
            break
      }
  }});
```